# HttpRequest.Files.Count is less than zero

Tags: c#, httprequest

HttpRequest.Saveas saves the following in a file

```
POST /VoicetrustAP/call.aspx HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, max-stale=0
Content-Length: 31988
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=osb_inet_multipart_boundary
Accept: */*
Expect: 100-continue
Host: 172.20.143.166
Referer: http://172.20.143.166/VoicetrustAP/call.aspx
User-Agent: AvayaVXI/2.0

--osb_inet_multipart_boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audioDataStream"; filename=20090313115600.ulaw
Content-Type: audio/x-wav
Content-Length: 31578

RIFFR{  WAVEfmt      @  @      fact    {  data { ...data removed....
--osb_inet_multipart_boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="callID"

00000056
--osb_inet_multipart_boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nextDialogID"

VTDC_CHECK_TD_AUDIO_DATA_ENR
--osb_inet_multipart_boundary--
```

But HttpRequest.Files.Count is less than zero ? Why?

Is it a bug in HttpRequest.Files?

Also I am able to access the data using formvariables. why?

Comment: What is the form that is being POST'ed?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect although I haven't test it myself that a "less than zero" count actually means "I don't know how many files there are, I have received all of the incoming data stream yet".